# 配列ヒープが期待（テスト）と異なった結果をかえす。

Tags: c++

今回の問題は配列ヒープがテストと異なった結果を返してしまうことです。うまくいくと、main.cppのテストと結果が一致するようになります。しかし、今の自分のプログラムは結果が一致しません。addItemメソッドは問題なさそうなのですが、おそらくgetItemメソッドに問題があると思われます。以下のプログラムを実行すると一回しか取り出されるはずの内60が3回も表示されてしまいます。教えていただきたいことはなぜ60が3回も表示されてしまうのかとどのようにコードを書けばテストと同じ結果が返ってくるのかが知りたいです。プログラムは以下の通りです。

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Heap.h"

using namespace std;



int main() {

    const int NUM_VALUES = 15;

    int heapVals[NUM_VALUES] = {10, 5, 30, 15, 20, 40, 60, 25, 50, 35, 45, 65, 70, 75, 55};

    cout << "Creating heap of default size (10)" << endl;
    Heap pile;

    // load the heap with values
    cout << "Now filling it with 15 values, should cause doubling of size" << endl << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
        pile.addItem(heapVals[i]);

    // remove values, should be in ascending order
    cout << "Now removing values to see if properly ordered" << endl;
    cout << " In order s/b: 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75" << endl;
    cout << " Actual order: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
        cout << pile.getItem() << " " ;
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

**Heap.cpp**

```
#include "Heap.h"

#include <iostream>

//default constructor
Heap::Heap()
{
    //the array size is STANDARD + 1
    arraySize = STANDARD + 1;
    //create an array it starts from 0 and ends at N(size+1)
    array = new int [arraySize];
    for(int i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        array[i] = EMPTY;
    }
}

//overloaded constructor
Heap::Heap(int size)
{
    //the array size is size + 1
    arraySize = size + 1;
    //create an array it starts from 0 and ends at N(size+1)
    array = new int[arraySize];
    for(int i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        array[i] = EMPTY;
    }
}

void Heap::addItem(int value)
{
    bool done = false;
    int parentIndex;
    int childIndex;

    //preincrement
    counter++;

    //if the array will be full by adding new value, double the array size
    if(counter >= arraySize)
    {
        arraySize *= 2;
        resize(arraySize);
    }

    //save the first index
    childIndex = counter;

    //add value at the next available index (counter)
    array[counter] = value;

    //if it's the first added value, do nothing
    if(counter == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    //if there're more than one value, place it correct position
    while(!done)
    {
        //get an index of parent
        parentIndex = childIndex / 2;

        //if child value >= parent value, finish the loop
        if(array[childIndex] >= array[parentIndex])
        {
            done = true;
        }

            //otherwise(child value < parent value)
        else
        {
            //save the parent value
            int temp = array[parentIndex];
            //store child value to parent
            array[parentIndex] = array[childIndex];
            //now, child shold have the saved parent value
            array[childIndex] = temp;

            //store parentIndex to childIndex for the next loop
            childIndex = parentIndex;

            //if the value became the root, stop the loop
            if(childIndex == 1)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }

    }
}

void Heap::resize(int size)
{
    //resize the array to the new size that is passed in

    //create new array to store previous values in it
    int *newArray = new int[size];

    for(int i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = EMPTY;
    }

    //move the previous values to new array
    for(int i = 1; i <= counter-1; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    //we don't need the old array anymore
    delete[] array;

    //array points to newArray so that the array gets new spaces
    array = newArray;
}

int Heap::getItem()
{
    //if array is empty
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    //save the smallest value in the array
    int smallest = array[1];

    //get the last added value
    int lastAdded = array[counter];
    //lastValue will be the root temporarily
    array[1] = lastAdded;
    //track the index of parent
    int parentIndex = 1;

    int done = false;

    //decrement counter
    counter--;

    //get the first index of the deepest level
    int height = getHeight(counter);
    int firstLeaf = getLeafFirst(height);


    //loop while done is true
    while(!done)
    {
        //get child index
        int childIndex = parentIndex * 2;

        //if both sides are empty, finish the loop
        if(array[childIndex] == EMPTY && array[parentIndex] == EMPTY)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //if both sides have value, compare, and get an index whose value is smaller
            if(array[childIndex+1] != EMPTY )
            {
                //get an index that has smaller value
                if(array[childIndex] >= array[childIndex+1])
                {
                    childIndex = childIndex + 1;
                }
            }

            //compare lastAdded and the value in the index
            //if the value in childIndex >= lastAdded, finish the loop
            if(array[childIndex] >= lastAdded)
            {
                done = true;
            }
                //otherwise(value < lastValue), swap the value
            else
            {
                //save the value
                int temp = array[childIndex];
                //array[childIndex] = lastAdded
                array[childIndex] = lastAdded;
                //array[parentIndex] =  the saved value
                array[parentIndex] = temp;
                //parentIndex should be childIndex for the next loop
                parentIndex = childIndex;
                //if parent reaches leaf, finish the loop
                if(parentIndex >= firstLeaf )
                {
                    done = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    //std::cout << std::endl << listElements() << " height and first: " << height << " " << firstLeaf << std::endl;
    //return the saved smallest value
    return smallest;
}

int Heap::getHeight(int value)
{
    int height = log2(value) + 1;
    return height;
}

int Heap::getLeafLast(int height)
{
    int num = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < height-1; i++)
    {
        num = num * 2 + 1;
    }
    return num;
}
int Heap::getLeafFirst(int height)
{
    int num = getLeafLast(height-1) + 1;
    return num;
}
```

**Heap.h**

```
#include <iostream>

const int STANDARD = 10;
const int EMPTY = -1;

class Heap {
private:
    int arraySize;
    int counter = 0;
    int *array;
public:
    Heap();
    Heap(int size);
    void addItem(int value);
    void resize(int value);
    int getItem();
    int getHeight(int value);
    int getLeafLast(int value);
    int getLeafFirst(int value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Heap.cpp**のgetItem()内のarray[parentIndex]がarray[childIndex+1]になっていないといけませんでした。

```
if(array[childIndex] >= array[parentIndex])
        {
            done = true;
        }
```

そしてさらに、`array[1] = lastAdded;`の下付近に`array[counter] = EMPTY`を入れれば解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

`Heap::getItem()`のwhileループで

```
int childIndex = parentIndex * 2;
```

と`childIndex`を算出していますが、`childIndex`が`counter`(要素数)を超えるケースがあり、
データ構造を破壊しているように見受けます。そのため、「60」が3回出力されていると思います。

`childIndex`が`counter`を超える場合、ループを打ち切ってはどうでしょうか。
具体的には、上記処理に続けてif文で判定する感じです。

```
int childIndex = parentIndex * 2;
if (childIndex > counter) {
    break;
}
```

---

なお、最後の1要素の状態で`getItem()`を呼び出した場合、`getHeight()`を引数「0」で
呼び出すことになり、`getHeight()`内で呼び出している`log2()`がエラーになるので、
`counter`が「1」の場合は、`getHeight()`を呼び出す前に最初の要素を返すようにすべきと思います。

#### 追記

コメントに回答します。

1. `counter`が1のときの対応ですが、コメント記載の内容でよいと思います。

コメント抜粋:

```
     int height;
     int firstLeaf;
     if(counter == 1)
     {
         height = 1;
         firstLeaf = 1;
     }
     else
     {
         height = getHeight(counter);
         firstLeaf  = getLeafFirst(height);
     }
```

2. 

> 確かに、最後の75以降を表示するのに時間がかかってしまいます。これはそれが問題なのでしょうか

断定はできませんが、その可能性は高いと思います。
(`getLeafLast()`では`height`分ループしているので、意図しない大きな値になっている場合、時間がかかる)

Comment: 「最後の1要素の状態でgetItem()を呼び出した場合、getHeight()を引数「0」で
呼び出すことになり、getHeight()内で呼び出しているlog2()がエラーになるので、
counterが「1」の場合は、getHeight()を呼び出す前に最初の要素を返すようにすべきと思います。」の部分を以下のようにやってみました。これで合っていますでしょうか。`int height;
    int firstLeaf;
    if(counter == 1)
    {
        height = 1;
        firstLeaf = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        height = getHeight(counter);
        firstLeaf  = getLeafFirst(height);
    }` 確かに、最後の75以降を表示するのに時間がかかってしまいます。これはそれが問題なのでしょうか

Comment: getHeight()とchildIndexの両方を修正して、再びコンパイルしてみたのですが、やはり、75だけ表示するのに時間がかかり、しばらくした後に75が表示され0が返ってきてプログラムが終了します。原因はほかにありそうです。

Comment: counterが0の時にgetHeight()の処理に時間が掛かっていたため、75の表示に時間が勝っていたみたいです。無事解決したました。ありがとうございました。